# appending a json file with PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have a json file to which i'm trying to append data.

The json file content looks like this .

```
{
    "KEYOP": ["01KEYOPS","23016/scripts/3rdParty/pusher-chat/assets/cobain.jpg"]
}
```

Below is my add_user.php

```
    <?php

$sentArray = $_POST['dataString1'];
$boxArray = file_get_contents('results.json');

$sentdata = json_decode($sentArray);
$getdata = json_decode($boxArray);


foreach($sentdata as $value)
    $getdata[] = $value;

print_r($getdata);
?>
```

> and below is my jquery script where i'm trying to send data to server

```
var myObj = {foo: "bar", "baz": "wockaflockafliz"};
                        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myObj, null, 2);
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "23016/scripts/3rdParty/pusher-chat/server/add_user.php",
                        data: { 'dataString1': jsonString },
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(response)
                        {               
                            alert(response);
                        }
                        });
```

The appended JSON file should look like this.

```
{
    "KEYOPS01!": ["01 KEYOPS","23016/scripts/3rdParty/pusher-chat/assets/cobain.jpg"],
     foo: "bar", 
     "baz": "wockaflockafliz"
}
```

I'm getting 500 Internal server error whenever I try to merge the data.

Comment: Check the server logs for more details about the 500.

Comment: Have you tried commenting every line out one by one to try to work out which is giving you a 500?  If you call the PHP directly in the browser, what do you get?  What's the content of boxArray?  Is it what you expect?  What's the content of $getdata and $sentdata?  Are they what you expect?

Comment: i'm kind of new to Php.Where would I find the log? on the web server? php installation folder?

Comment: if I echo $boxarray I get {
    "KEYOP": ["01KEYOPS","23016/scripts/3rdParty/pusher-chat/assets/cobain.jpg"]
} If I echo $sentarray I get {foo: "bar", "baz": "wockaflockafliz"};

Comment: echo of $sentdata is stdClass Object([foo] =>bar [baz] =>wockaflockafliz

Comment: what server are you using? apache on windows? xampp, linux? any distro? ubuntu, fedora? a hosting? is php installed as module?   
have you tried firebug to see if php expose the error msg? have you enabled error output in php, or error loging?

Comment: @JavierNeyra : it's windows server 2008 R2 with IIS version 6.x , php installed as a module .

Comment: I don't think it will clear a 500 error but I'd change the $getdata definition to `$getdata = json_decode($boxArray, true);` so you get an associative array rather than an object.

Comment: How should my myObj be declared for my JSON file to look like {"PLACOMBE": ["Preston Lacombe","23016/scripts/3rdParty/pusher-chat/assets/cobain.jpg"]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the log, but, if you want to merge the 2 arrays ($sentdata and $getdata), you should use something like array_merge()

http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php

with this:

```
foreach($sentdata as $value)
    $getdata[] = $value;
```

you are loosing your keys (and its slow)

and by the way... your appended json is not valid json...

Comment: The array I was trying to sent was a test, suppose I want to send "ALAMBRECHT": ["AMBER LAMBRECHT","23016/scripts/3rdParty/pusher-chat/assets/cobain.jpg"] which is exactly the way in the JSON file before appending  my  var myObj would be var myObj = {"ALAMBRECHT": '["AMBER LAMBRECHT","23016/scripts/3rdParty/pusher-chat/assets/cobain.jpg"]'}; right?

Comment: Great that worked . $result = array_merge((array)$sentdata, (array)$getdata);


print_r($result ); 

$file = fopen('results.json' ,'w+');
fwrite($file, json_encode($result));
fclose($file);

Comment: How should my myObj be declared for my JSON file to look like {"PLACOMBE": ["Preston Lacombe","23016/scripts/3rdParty/pusher-chat/assets/cobain.jpg"]}

Comment: Using php  `$myObj = json_encode(array("PLACOMBE"=>array("Preston Lacombe", "23016/scripts/3rdParty/pusher-chat/assets/cobain.jpg")));`